fill a list with positive numbers with try except method
I want to fill a list with positive numbers with try except method.
This is my code. But it doesn't raise an Error. What is wrong?
myList = [] 
maxLengthList = int(input("Enter number of items: "))

def get_positive_numbers():

    while len(myList) < maxLengthList:
        item = int(input("Enter your Item to the List: "))
        myList.append(item)
        # print (myList)

   
    try:             
        if item < 0: 
            raise ValueError    
        print(myList)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid number.")  
            

get_positive_numbers()

if i try to append list, my while loop doesn't work, it continuities asking to input numbers.  Please, can you help?

Why do you expect your code to raise an error ("But it doesn't raise an Error") ??

Please refine the statement: "my while loop doesn't work"

Please read: How to step through Python code to help debug issues?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The problem is to catch an error of a negative number while adding numbers from the user's input to the list with positive numbers. Now the question is solved, thank you.

If you expect to get an error while you are in the loop, throw the error in the loop too, because that way it would only throw an error after the input. Fixed code:
(the Python syntax is sensitive to indentation, this determines the structure)
myList = [] 
maxLengthList = int(input("Enter number of items: "))

def get_positive_numbers():
    while len(myList) < maxLengthList:
        try:
            item = int(input("Enter your Item to the List: "))
            if item < 0:
                raise ValueError("Invalid number.")
            myList.append(item)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
    print(myList)
            
get_positive_numbers()


can u flag my answer as correct? :)

I don't have enough reputation to add a vote.

@apprentice You don't need reputation to accept an answer. Please read What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"? and What should I do when someone answers my question?.
